# how to find particular word from one table which is present in table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

**table_name1 : citymaster**

```
id cityname
1  Florida
2  Newyork
3  Hydrabad
```

**table_name2 : Details**

```
id detail
1  I am from washington
2  Newyork is beautiful
3  It is said that, Florida is very beautiful
```

**table_name3 : Cityfromdetails**

```
(Which is the output table)
id City    
1  not available
2  newyork
3  Florida
```

I want third table should contain onlt city name from the table details. If city is not present in the CItymaster then output should be 'not available'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left join with a like

```
select d1.id, coalesce(c2.cityname, 'Not Available') as City
from details d1
left join citymaster c2
  on d1.detail like '%' + c2.cityname + '%'
```

Or we can use SQL Server's `CHARINDEX()` function:

```
select d1.id, coalesce(c2.cityname, 'Not Available') as City
from details d1
left join citymaster c2
    on charindex(c2.cityname, d1.detail) > 0;
```

## Demo

Comment: I don't know why cross join popped into my mind, but your solution is totally the way to go here +1.